# layers in opentripplanner webapp

Tags: openlayers-2, java, web, transit

I am customizing the opentripplanner webapp according to my needs. it has 5 different base layers. but in code (in map.js and OpenLayersUtils) i can't find where it adds these layers to map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the source directly from the [git repo here](https://github.com/openplans/OpenTripPlanner) of opentripplanner.  I think it's somewhere [in this file](https://github.com/openplans/OpenTripPlanner/blob/master/opentripplanner-webapp/src/main/webapp/js/otp/core/Map.js) where they setup the map.

There you see:

```
 initialize : function(config)
{
    otp.configure(this, config);

    this.map = otp.util.OpenLayersUtils.makeMap(this.mapDiv, this.options);
    if (this.baseLayer == null)
    {
        this.baseLayer = otp.util.OpenLayersUtils.makeMapBaseLayer(this.map, this.baseLayerOptions);
        this.cartoLayer = this.baseLayer;
        this.orthoLayer = this.baseLayer;
    }
    else
    {
        this.map.addLayers(this.baseLayer);
        this.cartoLayer = this.map.layers[0];
        this.orthoLayer = this.map.layers[1];

        if(this.baseLayer.length > 1 && this.plannerOptions && this.plannerOptions.showLayerSwitcher !== false) {
            this.showLayerSwitcher=true;
        } else {
            this.showLayerSwitcher=false;
        }
    }
    this.map.setBaseLayer(this.baseLayer, true);
```

In there is a line:

```
otp.configure(this, config);
```

That looks like a variable thing, a bit below that you see that this otp config object if exists is being used to set up layers

```
this.map.addLayers(this.baseLayer);
```

Looking at the rest of the code, it looks like you have 3 basic layers: WMS + the carto + ortho layer.  The other 2 come from something dynamically configured it seems.  That would be my first guess.  The WMS layer is defined in [makeMap, in this file](https://github.com/openplans/OpenTripPlanner/blob/master/opentripplanner-webapp/src/main/webapp/js/otp/util/OpenLayersUtils.js)